# написание денежной единицы

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как грамотно будет: на сумму 958 723 рублей или рубля?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, отметьте его галочкой. Вы также можете нажать на треугольник, чтобы отблагодарить автора.

Answer (score 1):

В конце 3 - поэтому 3 рубля.

Ответ: 958 723 рубля.